# Asynchronous web service call in flex and java

Tags: java, web-services, apache-flex, asynchronous

How can i access to my Asynchronous web service in java? I made this thing in Flex Builder, and it`s pretty easy: just add web service throw "Data -> Connect to Web Service -> Enter the URL of wsdl" and add this lines:

```
private function result(e:ResultEvent):void
{
     trace(e.result.toString());
}

private function fault(e:FaultEvent):void
{
     trace(e.toString());
}

var d:DomainAuth = new DomainAuth();
d.AuthFuncName(login, pass);
d.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, result);
d.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, fault);
```

How can i do this in Java using eclipse EE?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092083/using-and-testing-web-services-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to do a SOAP web service client in java if I understand you correctly.
JAX-WS can be your friend. The following code is from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html)

```
package simpleclient;

import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceRef;
import helloservice.endpoint.HelloService;
import helloservice.endpoint.Hello;

public class HelloClient {
    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation="http://localhost:8080/
        helloservice/hello?wsdl")
    static HelloService service;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        HelloClient client = new HelloClient();
        client.doTest(args);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void doTest(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Retrieving the port from
                 the following service: " + service);
        Hello port = service.getHelloPort();
        System.out.println("Invoking the sayHello operation
                 on the port.");

        String name;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            name = args[0];
        } else {
            name = "No Name";
        }

        String response = port.sayHello(name);
        System.out.println(response);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```