# SOAP call from Java programmatically

Tags: java, soap

I am new to Java SOAP call on a web service.  I would like to invoke a soap call by clicking on a button within my maven project.

Could you please guide me what are the steps that are needed to send a SOAP envelope request with two values to a specific post?

This what I need to do:

- Set the URL of the web service,
- Set the request header,
- Set the envelope to send,
- Send the envelope and get the response text.

Comment: web service clients are usually generated by tools. wsimport comes with the oracle jdk

Comment: check out http://cxf.apache.org/

Comment: You can easily get Eclipse (or most other IDEs) to generate the necessary code from the WSDL.

Comment: @Gere I have look at the cxf before but I didn't understand what are the step I should follow

Comment: @0xCAFEBABE could you please elaborate your comment? as I am new to this.

Comment: Everything you need is listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092083/using-and-testing-web-services-in-eclipse).